# Circular imports django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have wrote this code in my models.py file.

As you see the code, I have a class called File and also I have imported in models.py the same class.

Now it gives me this error while migration:

Cannot import name "File" from 'uploadapp.models'

I understand it's the error for circular (recursive) import. But how can I solve this?

```
from django.db import models
from .models import File

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

Comment: Remove the `from .models import File`, you import the `models` module *in* the `models` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the `from .models import File`. It makes no sense to import the module in the same module:

```
from django.db import models
# from .models import File

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```